# Auto-redirect static HTML5 page by language

Tags: html, docker, nginx

i have a static html5 website that does not use javascript. Now I want to integrate an automatic speech recognition into the website, which leads you to a different page depending on your language.

That's how I imagined it:

```
en -> main.com
de -> main.com/de
fr -> main.com/fr
```

To realize this I have added the following meta data into my website:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="main.html" hreflang="en" />
<link rel="alternate" href="main-de.html" hreflang="de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="main-fr.html" hreflang="fr" />
```

Unfortunately I can't get on with docker and nginx now and maybe one of you could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a Docker or nginx issue.

From what I can gather the `hreflang="en"` is more for SEO / google crawling etc, so you still need some way to make an automatic redirect.

There are multiple ways of doing this, but the best way would be with a little bit of Javascript, in theory you could do this serverside using nginx using IP addresses, but that's not a good idea, the browser language should be king here.

So with a little bit of Javascript you could maybe do ->

```
if (navigator.language.split('-')[0] === 'de') location.href = 'main-de.html';`
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation but unfortunately I want to solve it without js

Answer (score 0):

You could use nginx to switch on the Accept-Language request header to issue a redirect to the proper file. There is a module called nginx_accept_language that might do the trick, though you could also use if-else phase handler in the nginx config (one of the few times it would be used as it was intended) if you don't want to compile in extra modules.

I have no experience using the nginx_accept_language module myself, but it appears to do what you want. The code is here: https://github.com/giom/nginx_accept_language_module

This example configuration from the docs does basically what you are looking to do:

```
location / { 
    set_from_accept_language $lang pt en;
    if ( $request_uri ~ ^/$ ) { 
        rewrite ^/$ /$lang redirect;
        break; 
    }
}
```